# BeautifulSoup: How to skip a child node within a find_all?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code to scrape this page:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = u''
# Find Starting point
start = soup.find('div', class_='main-content-column')
if start:
    news.image_url_list = []
    for item in start.find_all('p'):
```

The problem I'm facing is that it also grabs the `<p>` inside `<div class="type-gallery">`, which I would like to avoid. But can't find a way to achieve it.
Any ideas please?

[image]

Comment: There is no need to add your specific application of my general principles. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want *direct children*, not just any descendant, which is what `element.find_all()` returns. Your best bet here is to use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead:

```
for item in soup.select('div.main-content-column > div > p'):
```

The `>` operator limits this to `p` tags that are a direct child nodes of `div` tags within the `div` with the given class. You can make this as specific as you like; adding in the `itemprop` attribute for example:

```
for item in soup.select('div.main-content-column > div[itemprop="articleBody"] > p'):
```

The alternative is to loop over the [`element.children` iterable](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
start = soup.find('div', class_='main-content-column')
if start:
    news.image_url_list = []
    for item in start.children:
        if item.name != 'div':
            # skip children that are not <div> tags
            continue
        for para in item.children:
            if item.name != 'p':
                # skip children that are not <p> tags
                continue
```

Comment: Very interesting idea. `soup.select('div > p')` returns me a number of paragraphs to begin with. But `soup.select('div.main-content-column > p')` returns an empty list.

Comment: @Houman: then your div doesn't *directly* contain the `p` tags. Perhaps you wanted `div.main-content-column > div > p`

Comment: ah , yes its because there is a div in between. Is there a way to specifiy the div with `itemprop="articlebody"` instead of generic `> div >` ?  ALternatively I could use your second approach

Comment: You can use `div[itemprop="articleBody"]` to select on attributes.

Comment: You mean as CSS selector like this? `for item in soup.select('div.main-content-column > div[itemprop="article body"] > p'):`  Because that fails with "Unsupported or invalid CSS selector"

Comment: @Houman: I had a typo in the attribute selector; it's `soup.select('div.main-content-column > div[itemprop="articleBody"] > p')` (and I corrected my comment).

Comment: Genius.  This works now.  And I think its faster than the explicit solution I have in my updated question, correct?

Comment: It's still implemented in pure Python, the speed will be about the same.